# KnockoutJS: How to avoid running a viewmodel function on applyBindings?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm a little puzzled by some code I plunked together that doesn't behave quite as I'd expect.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong (and given the late hour here, it might be something simple), but I'm looking for some clarity on why this happens.

I'm using:

- jQuery 1.10.2
- Knockout 2.3.0
- Bootstrap 3.0.3

### The Problem

- I define a function in my ViewModel, which sets an observable to a certain value.

  - This is not called from anywhere else in my code.
- I define a `data-bind="click: AddAnnouncement"` binding on a button that's part of a button group.
- When `ko.applyBindings(vm)` is called, the `AddAnnouncement` function fires, giving me an undesired result long before I click on anything.

### The Code in Question

Can be found in a JSFiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/SeanKilleen/v8ReS/.

Essentially, I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {

    ViewModel: function(){
        'use strict';
        var self = this;

        self.AddingAnnouncement = ko.observable(false);

        self.AddAnnouncement = function(){
            self.AddingAnnouncement(true); 
        };

        self.Start = function(){
            self.AddingAnnouncement(false);
        };

        self.Start();
    }
};

var vm;

$(document).ready(function(){
'use strict';

vm = new MyNamespace.ViewModel();

 ko.applyBindings(vm); 
    //do something with jQuery? Bind a VM?
});
```

My binding code is also pretty elementary (I thought):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><abbr Title="Announcement" data-bind="click: AddAnnouncement()">A</abbr>

            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" data-bind="visible: AddingAnnouncement() == true">
            <h1>Add a new announcement</h1>

    </div>
</div>
```

### What I *think* it's doing

I think the code in question is doing the following:

- Defining a namespace called `MyNamespace` (albeit probably not in the best way; this may be part of the problem?)
- Defining a `ViewModel` object inside the namespace
- Giving the `ViewModel` object an observable called `AddingAnnouncment` and a function called `AddAnnouncement`, which sets `AddingAnnouncement` to true.
- Defines a `Start` method which ensures that `AddingAnnouncement` is set to false by default;
- Calls the `Start` method as the last step in its initialization.

### What am I Missing Here?

I think I'm not grasping some standard behavior of JavaScript or something about the way knockout binds models, but it seems like when applying the bindings, knockout executes all of the functions, even for the click bindings. However, that doesn't make sense to me and so I'm betting I'm wrong.

Someone enlighten me? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whooops! The answer to that question turned out to be right under my nose; indeed, all I had to do was write **that entire darn question** before I saw it. :)

The problem is with my binding:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><abbr Title="Announcement" data-bind="click: AddAnnouncement()">A</abbr>
```

Note a very important distinction: `AddAnnouncement()`. The `()` matters quite a bit in this case.

When knockout assigns its binding, it does so by directly referencing what you enter. Since I entered `AddAnnouncement()`, it assigned the binding to the output of the function that had been run once, rather than the function itself which would be executed at a later time.

The best way to do it would have been to use `AddAnnouncment`, without paranetheses, like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><abbr Title="Announcement" data-bind="click: AddAnnouncement">A</abbr>
```

This does not execute the function upon applying bindings.

While I forgot to avoid such a simple mistake, I hope it saves someone else time in the future. The working JSFiddle can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/SeanKilleen/v8ReS/4/.

Comment: you can also wrap in inside an anonymous function like this : `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><abbr Title="Announcement" data-bind="click: function() { AddAnnouncement(); }">A</abbr>`

Answer (score 1):

We usually confuse when to use parentheses **()** when we bind **View** with **ViewModel**.

As when you bind `AddAnnouncement` function, you directly bind with function call like `AddAnnouncement()`. That why the `AddAnnouncement` function call when you bind using `ko.applyBindings` even though we didn't click the button, the function call already fire.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <abbr Title="Announcement" data-bind="click: AddAnnouncement()">
               A
            </abbr>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

so we change as below

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <abbr Title="Announcement" data-bind="click: AddAnnouncement">
               A
            </abbr>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vr3Lv/)

Comment: Hi Goddard -- thanks for jumping in to help me out! Even though I already answered my own question (I'd totally missed the parens issue), I wanted to take a second to welcome you to StackOverflow. Being willing to jump in is awesome. I also recommend elaborating on your answers to go into "how" and "why" questions behind them. This will make your answer more likely to be selected and upvoted in the future. Thanks again for your answer!